# Serialization Exception

Tags: binaryformatter

what is Exception "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed." in the my code?

```
BinaryFormatter t = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream n = new MemoryStream();
t.Serialize(n, j);

BinaryFormatter q = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream x = new MemoryStream();
q.Deserialize(n);
```

Comment: You need better variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After serializing the object to the stream, the stream's `Position` is at the end.
Therefore, there is nothing more in the stream for the deserializer to read.

You need to rewind the stream, by setting `n.Position = 0`.